# webpage title

Tags: php

In My Website I have main urls such as

h**p://www.sy-stu.com/stu/music.php

The Title of the page is Syrian Students ... Music Center

But when i get into the subpages such as

h**p://www.sy-stu.com/stu/music.php?module=MusicServer&page=browse&ViewType=Albums&Artistid=305

The Title still the same how can i modify it to show somethin else BUT keeping the original page Title in the main pages.

So My goal is to keep the old Title in the main pages and change the Title In the subpages

Comment: And your question is what now?

Comment: how to change a subpage title whie Im using modules

Comment: What Framework/CMS are using that produces these pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to script out the title like:

```
<head>
  <title><?php getTitle(); ?></title>
</head>
```

And this would know where it was and produce the correct title.

Comment: and for example If i have the artist name as a title how and what the php getTitle(); might include or work I not pro so can you exlain more IF possible

Comment: see my answer to see what getTitle() might include...

function getTitle() {
    $subTitle = 'Nelly Furtado';
    echo $subTitle;
}

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I've visited your website and see you have a custom made CMS. The CMS probably uses modules, therefore I think the 'title' part of the output html is generated in another file than music.php.

**You have to look for a file that contains code that generates <head> and <title> tags.** This file can be located anywhere, it is not possible for us to know where the developer locates his file. Anyway, in this file you will be able to see HOW the code 'receives' information about the title that needs to be printed. **Look for usage of this code in the music.php file.**

The information about the artist is available somewhere in the music.php file. You somehow have to pass that information to the code that 'provides' title or head information to the code in the file you had to find at first...

Please understand that your question is very difficult to answer properly with this little information, and maybe worse (no offence) this little experience.

Old answer:

```
<head>
  <title>Syrian Students Music Center <? echo $subTitle ?></title>
</head>
```